# GPS with QGIS--what happened to the capture point?

Tags: qgis, gps, gpstools

I have been using QGIS for years but when v. 2 came out and important functionality seems to no longer work.  In 1.8 the "capture point" or "capture line" buttons on the GPS panel would work.  Ever since 2.0 I have been unable to make these work.  What happened?  Maybe it is something different than QGIS because I also have switched to using windows 8 tablets in the field environment where I use the system.

btw--a related question, QGIS doesn't seem to be able to capture Z information in any case.  Capturing Z for points, to me, is an essential feature that seems missing.  Maybe I'm missing something here that is in v. 2 that I just don't understand.
TP

Comment: I would recommend you split your question in two questions, as they are very different.

Comment: You read the document but recording does not work http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/live_GPS_tracking.html? And you have editable layer of correct datatype in your project?